# How to combine PCA and MCA on mixed data?

Tags: python, categorical-data

Suppose I have mixed data and (python) code which is capable of doing [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (principal component analysis) on continuous predictors and [MCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) (multiple correspondence analysis) on nominal predictors. Is it possible to combine results from PCA and MCA into one?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use [Factor analysis of mixed data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis_of_mixed_data).

It allows you to do dimension reduction on a complete data set.

A R implementation could be found in the FactoMineR package. But this function struggle when you have a high number of data/columns.

I am not aware of the existence of the equivalent in python.

Comment: Thank you, I have read about FAMD before, which unfortunately seems to have only R support - hence my question. The least I can do now is to treat results of both methods (PCA & MCA) in separation. However, if there is a way to 'mix' them together to yield a monolithic dataset then this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that my dataset is big enough as to make the MCA implementation at hand to run out of memory.

Comment: This is a recurrent issue I get with the R implementation. If you have a limited set of variable, try to weight your observations. Or use only a subset of your observation. Otherwise, you could try to transform your numeric variable into ordinal category or to transform your qualitative variables into flags.

Answer (score 3):

You can find FAMD implementation for Python [here](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing in Python and I came the [prince](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prince/0.2.6) package that has FAMD implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment so answering here
@Edo prince Package has only CA, MCA and PCA PAckages in it.  I do not see any FAMD in here.

```
dir(prince)

['CA', 'MCA', 'PCA', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'ca', 'mca', 'pca', 'plot', 'svd']
```

Comment: [import prince.famd](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince/blob/master/prince/famd.py)